# How to do mouse hover over HTML and click an option from the drop down after hover in selenium web driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

Any one can please tell me how to mouse hover on the menu drop down and click any option from the drop down in SElenium using C#

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Actions`. First define the complete action and then perform it.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHover = driver.findElement(By.id("ID_Menu"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHover);

WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ID_Item"));
actions.moveToElement(subLink);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Hope help!

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i find element by the inner html of the tag? because i have HTML which has no ID.

Comment: You could find web elements using any other criteria. The actions would work anyway. Post your HTML if you want some help. Anyway, take a look at this http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements

Comment: i have figure out how to get HTML with ID or any other attribute, I have an HTML which has an id and when i run the test an exception is generating unable to find element with id == 'my html id' and it is exist in that html page. Can you tell me how to figure it out.

Comment: Could you post your HTML to have a look?

Comment: <td id="ctl00_ucMenu_MainMenun1" title="User Management" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)">
<table class="MenuRoot ctl00_ucMenu_MainMenu_4" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="white-space:nowrap;">
<a class="ctl00_ucMenu_MainMenu_1 MenuRoot ctl00_ucMenu_MainMenu_3" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucMenu$MainMenu','TreeView.aspx?CATEGORY=Configuration&Title=&id=CONFIG_USER_MANAGER&HELPURL=advconcepts_custom_data_dimensions.htm')">User Management